# How To Write *nix's basename in C 

Tags: c, substring

I want to extract the base name from a string, like

```
/opt/home/etc/sample
```

That is, I want to parse a string of large length returning `sample`, or the substring
after the last `/` character. The string can be of any length.

How could this be done?

Comment: Use a `strrpos()` and `substr()` implementation.

Comment: @alex, these are C++ functions. C has `strrchr`.

Comment: @ugoren I forget a lot of C. You could always implement them in C :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strtok_r

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="This/a/sample/string";
  char * pch;
  char * ans;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok_r (str,"/");
  if(pch==NULL)
  ans = str;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    ans = pch;
    pch = strtok_r (NULL, "/");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

P.S please check the code for some small errors

Comment: Thanks nischayn22. strtok gives me the expected output.

Comment: -1: not thread-safe/reentrant + fails badly if `str` does not contain a `/`.

Comment: @PaulR thanks for pointing that out, could you explain thread-safe part?

Comment: `strtok` is not re-entrant - see the man page - use `strtok_r`

Comment: Also note re your latest edit - you can't just check `ans == NULL` since it's not initialised and will be undefined if `str` does not contain a `/`. And note that to match the behaviour of `basename` you should be returning the entire string if there are no path separators.

Comment: It's improved a little, but you're still using `strtok` instead of `strtok_r`.

Answer (score 6):

```
char *input = "/opt/home/etc/sample";
char *output = NULL;

output = strrchr(input, '/');

if(output != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

Or otherway is that you can try to parse it all by yourself (Below code is just a sample and doesn't handle all error and boundary conditions, which you can try and learn by yourself)

```
char *input = "/opt/home/etc/sample";
int len = 0;
char *temp = NULL;

len = strlen(input);
temp = input + (len-1);
len--;

while((*temp != '/') && (len >= 0))
{
  temp--;
  len--;
}


if(len>=0)
{
   printf("%s\n", temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `basename` / `dirname` functions in POSIX. Their return value will point to either static memory or some suffix of the input, so there's no need to free it. This may be way easier than to split the string yourself:

```
  // assuming you own *path:
  char *file = basename(path);
  char *dir = dirname(path);   //that's all!
```

They also handle the special case when `path` is `"."` or `".."` or `"foo/"` (then, basename is `"."` - the correct thing).

*But beware if you don't own the string*: They take a non-const argument, and they may modify it.

If you really need to use `basename` on a `const char *`, the solution is about the same

```
  #include <libgen.h>  // POSIX

  void die(const char * errormessage);

  /* version of basename(3) that does not modify its argument.
   * This assumes that "path" is correctly 0-terminated!
   * Please free() the return value after use. */
  char * basename_safe(const char * path)
  {
    char * result;
    char * what_basename_says;

    if (!path) {
      // return a pointer to ".":
      result = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
      if (!result) die("malloc failed!");
      result[0] = '.';
      result[1] = 0;
      return result;
    }

    // in case path is the empty string, we need 2 chars to store the result ".",
    // so add 2:
    result = malloc((2 + strlen(path)) * sizeof(char));
    if (!result) die("malloc failed");

    // basename wants write access to its argument:
    strcpy(result, path);

    what_basename_says = basename(result);
    // now what_basename_says actually may be a pointer into *result.

    strcpy(result, what_basename_says);
    // to allow for free(result)

    return result;
  }
```

But, as I said before: if you know that you can modify `*path`, you may as well use `basename` without all this.

Comment: `strcpy(result, what_basename_says);`: As you say, `what_basename_says` may be a pointer into `*result`. When `s1` and `s2` overlap, the behaviour of `strcpy(s1, s2)` is **undefined**.